# Could not Publish (TypeError): null is not and object (evaluating b.g.) - Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to publish an RMarkdown document to my RPubs account, but I get the next error when clicking on "Publish":

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/.../File.Rmd': No such file or directory
```

It also pops up a window saying the next two warnings:

First pop up: "Could not Publish - Error ocurred while executing method"
Second pop up: "Could not Publish - (TypeError): null is not an object evaluating 'b.g.')

My R version is 3.4.2, RStudio version is 1.1.383, knitr version is 1.17.
I have also checked is the working directory contains the files I'm using at the script, and all seems properly set.

This error only happens when I click on Publish. If I try to knit to HTML or to PDF it works. I have tried to restart and reinstall also both R and RStudio but the error persists.

Has anyone had the same error and knows how to solve it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is the file saved? Are you in the correct directory?
Please check `getwd()`.

Comment: Yes, I have also checked that the file is saved and it is in the same directory where I'm working in.

Comment: Have you tried to logout your Rpubs account and re login? Is very hard to see what is the issue without an example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The problem was that the path of the working directory contained an accent. I changed the path to another folder without accents and it worked.